# type operator for removing from a tagged union

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

Is it possible to remove a specific type literal from a tagged union / discriminated union? How would I write such a type?

Given this type:

```
type MyUnion = {
  kind: "foo"
  foo: number
} | {
  kind: "bar"
  bar: string
} | {
  kind: "baz"
  baz: boolean
}
```

I want to remove the `{kind: "baz", baz: boolean}` type literal. Is it possible to write a `type RemoveTag<T, K, V>` such that:

```
type MyUnionWithoutBaz = RemoveTag<MyUnion, "kind", "baz">
```

yields:

```
type MyUnionWithoutBaz = {
  kind: "foo"
  foo: number
} | {
  kind: "bar"
  bar: string
}
```

?

Comment: Your `RemoveTag` utility should probably also ask for which key to check, or else you're hardcoding `"kind"` and at that point you might as well forgo the type utility and just write `Exclude<MyUnion, {kind: "baz"}>`.  (Using `T` as a specific type is potentially confusing as people expect that to be a generic type parameter; so I'm replacing it with `MyUnion`) Anyway it could look like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WYvKrw).  Does that meet your needs?   If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, I think that's it! Also, you're right that I inadvertently hard-coded `"kind"`, I will update my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [the `Exclude<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers) to filter members from out a union `T` which are not assignable to another type `U`.  Your `RemoveTag` type could therefore be written as

```
type RemoveTag<T, K extends keyof T, V> =
  Exclude<T, Record<K, V>>
```

depending on your use cases (if the discriminant property is [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) then it wouldn't work as is).  For your example, it produces:

```
type MyUnionWithoutBaz = RemoveTag<MyUnion, "kind", "baz">
/* type TWithoutBaz = {
    kind: "foo";
    foo: number;
} | {
    kind: "bar";
    bar: string;
} */
```

as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiCqA7Alge0VAvFA3gKCigGtlEATALigCIAzVVagqe1KxAVwFsAjCAJzwBfKAB9czEuSrUeAQ35NC8-lQDOwfqQDmwsRMJTKNeQC8lUM1R4MANhDmJhePKEhQAShC6oAbhAAVOW0AHgCAGigAaSgIAA9gCHI1YggQVFooCKgANQA+LGYAUTiAY1sOMggwyK9S1H4yEKjI-LyXN2g4JDREAHVkYAALVA5gACE5UyxPbz9A4JDulHRI6iNqNbNqdoB6ACooTqyB4dGJqZn8QkNSYzoGagBuZkJWdm4+fheRcWubowyFTPV6WBTqTQ6H5Qfa7IA)

Comment: Personally I find it more idiomatic to write `Exclude<MyUnion, {kind: 'baz'}>` since this makes clearer the roles of `'kind'` and `'baz'`. This is an elegant way to achieve exactly the OP's desired syntax, though.